# Variable limit number of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, checkbox, limit

I would like to limit number of checkboxes not with a fix number (i.e.2), but I want pre-select this limit.

I'm able to limit in a [fix way (working example)](https://jsfiddle.net/ux3qn3Lz/)

```
 <p>Select your favorite countries below:</p>

<form id="world" name="world">
Select the limit<select id="limit" onchange="this.form.submit()"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select><br/>
 <input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> USA<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> Canada<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> Japan<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> China<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> France<br />
</form>


function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
var checkgroup=checkgroup
var limit=limit
for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
    checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
    var checkedcount=0
    for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
        checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0
    if (checkedcount>limit){
        alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes")
        this.checked=false
        }
    }
}
}


checkboxlimit(document.forms.world.countries, 2)
```

but I'm not able to to change the limit in this [variable way (not working)](https://jsfiddle.net/ux3qn3Lz/2/)

```
<p>Select your favorite countries below:</p>

<form id="world" name="world">
Select the limit<select id="limit" onchange="this.form.submit()"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> USA<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> Canada<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> Japan<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> China<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> France<br />
</form>



function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
var checkgroup=checkgroup
var limit=limit
for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
    checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
    var checkedcount=0
    for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
        checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0
    if (checkedcount>limit){
        alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes")
        this.checked=false
        }
    }
}
}

var e = document.getElementById("limit");
var limit = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
checkboxlimit(document.forms.world.countries, limit)
```

Comment: The question is tagged with jQuery, but not javascript, are you using jQuery at all ?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution: https://jsfiddle.net/g6cyegnt/1/

All you have to do is, do not submit the form on the change event of limit control. Handle the change event separately as shown in the code / fiddler.

```
<p>Select your favorite countries below:</p>

<form id="world" name="world">
    Select the limit<select id="limit"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select><br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> USA<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> Canada<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> Japan<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> China<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="countries" /> France<br />
</form>

function checkboxlimit(checkgroup, limit){
    var checkgroup=checkgroup
    var limit=limit
    for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++){
        checkgroup[i].onclick=function(){
        var checkedcount=0
        for (var i=0; i<checkgroup.length; i++)
            checkedcount+=(checkgroup[i].checked)? 1 : 0
        if (checkedcount>limit){
            alert("You can only select a maximum of "+limit+" checkboxes")
            this.checked=false
            }
        }
    }
}

$('input[name="countries"]').on('change', function(){
var limit = $('#limit').find(':selected').val();
checkboxlimit(document.forms.world.countries, limit)
});
```